# HTML project path confusion

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am writing an HTML/CSS/JS project on my localhost.
The project root is found at `http://localhost/projects/project1/`.

I want to know if it is possible to make the HTML files treat my project
root as its' base URL so that referencing the same javascript/css files
doesn't depend on the path of the HTML file(unless I reference relative to
current directory).

Here is my project structure:

- projects

  - project1

    - index.html
    - pages (directory)
    - page1.html
    - page2.html
    - apps(directory)
    - app1(directory)

      - index.html
      - style.css
      - app.js
    - deps(directory)
    - jquery.js

As you can see, to refer to jquery.js inside my `/projects/project1/index.html`, 
 
I have to write:

```
<script src="deps/jquery.js"></script>
```

To refer to jquery.js inside `/projects/project1/pages/index1.html`, 
I have to write

```
<script src="../deps/jquery.js"></script>
```

To refer to jquery.js inside `http://localhost/projects/project1/apps/app1/index.html`, 
I have to write

```
<script src="../../jquery.js"></script>
```

At which point I am not sure I wrote the correct number of `../`s and can easily 
cause errors.

Worse, If i reorder my directories around or rename them, it means I have to deal with
rewriting the paths again, which can be very daunting.

I have thought of various ways to address them none of which are appealing(although option 3 comes close).

---

Thoughts/Attempts:

1. I tried playing with .htaccess RewriteEngine/RewriteBase but nothing worked.
2. I could just create a new server for each project as NodeJS makes it really easy to do so. 
    This way, each server has the directory as its' static path and is '/'. 
    The problem with this approach is that this managing 
    many servers up at once on different ports which can be confusing.
3. I could set an absolute path variable in .htaccess via

   ```
    SetEnv PROJECT_PATH /projects/project1/
   ```

   However doing this means I have to open .htaccess each time I move the folder
    or rename it and change the PROJECT_PATH. This may seem simple but if you
    give the project to somebody else and they don't know how .htaccess works, 
    it is very painful to explain how to find this path, and how to change it,
    and even more problematic if the .htaccess is longer than one line.

   Ideally, I want this SetEnv to figure out the folder it is inside by itself,
    but I don't know how to accomplish this. This also has a problem that the pathing becomes dependent on the PHP preprocessing which makes it painful to move to another server that does not have .htaccess or PHP such as NodeJS(which can still invoke php but even then it needs to deal with .htaccess).

---

I want to know if it is possible to either

1. Make .htaccess file create an environment variable containing deduced path
   of this particular .htaccess file so that php files inside this directory can
   do pathing relative to `$_ENV{PROJECT_ROOT}`. This way if the project is moved or shared, it will still work without needing to modify .htaccess.
2. Make .htaccess to force HTML files contained in the same or lower directories that all "/" references treat this directory as the root.

Or if there are other things to address this issue that I have not thought of.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Why can't you use relative urls?

Comment: because I want the same dependency to be referred to the same way in each file referencing it, otherwise the project becomes hard to change, and very difficult to scale. it also makes generating html files harder.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry, you can try this:

1) In your file ***httpd.conf***, add the following line at the end:

```
Redirect permanent /deps http://localhost/projects/project1/deps/
```

2) Restart apache service

3) Refresh your index page(/projects/project1/pages/index1.html)

I have used something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/deps/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

</html>

<?php

echo "welcome to index"

?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause /deps in all projects to redirect to this location though? What i I have other projects that have different dependencies, e.g. jquery.js is jquery 3 rather  than 2.2, or if I want to have a /scripts directory that contains app.js which is different for each project/app. I know hard redirects work but I may as well create a /deps folder and accomplish the same thing. I want it to be relative only to a specific folder.

Comment: If your projects uses the same libraries, this could be useful, but if you need to use different folders, consider to rewrite your paths manually...

Comment: I already do this for "common" things across all projects, but it becomes difficult for "only-this-project" folders, and trying to refer to them from various levels of the project. At the moment it is very difficult for me to write non-flat projects due to this constraint, as it means any small change would require lots of manual correcting of every html file..

Comment: What you can do is use a folder reference, outside the projects, at root level, and afterwards you can give permissions to access from inside...

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**How do I access a directory outside of my document root?**

This explain how to give users access to a directory that is outside of your directory root on Windows.

Assuming that your directory is located at C:/www/newfolder/ then you would create the following in your httpd.conf file.

```
Alias /newfolder/ "C:/www/newfolder/"

<Directory "C:/www/newfolder">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now, when a user goes to **www.domain.com/newfolder/** then they see the folder that is outside your document root and it appears in the browser to be a directory contained below the document root..

One thing to consider is that if you have virtualhosts, then an alias works for every virtualhost, so try to use uncommon names for your alias.

Hope this helps